# Compare data from database and Excel (2 types of data source) SSIS

Tags: database, excel, ssis

Does exist easy way to compare data from database and Excel? If Excel contain Mora data which isn't in database I must insert them to database.
Can you show me easy example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read in the excel data, convert it into appropriate data types, do a lookup against the relevant database column and if not found send the data to the table destination so it can be inserted.

Google SSIS tutorials for more details. Or ask another more specfic question if you get stuck.